# String to LocalDate

Tags: java, jodatime

How can i convert a string to a `LocalDate`?

I have seen examples like:

```
LocalDate dt = new LocalDate("2005-11-12");
```

But my strings are like:

```
2005-nov-12
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As you use Joda Time, you should use `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
final LocalDate dt = dtf.parseLocalDate(yourinput);
```

---

If using Java 8 or later, then refer to [hertzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538939/1093528)

Comment: Also submitted an edit for the format "yyyy-MMM-dd". YYYY is year of era, and (more egregiously) DD is day of year.

Comment: the answer is slightly wrong... for joda time, the class to use is DateTimeFormat, not DateTimeFormatter.   In other words, call DateTimeFormat.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parseLocalDate(yourInput);

Answer (score 263):

## java.time

Since Java 1.8, you can achieve this without an extra library by using the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
formatter = formatter.withLocale( putAppropriateLocaleHere );  // Locale specifies human language for translating, and cultural norms for lowercase/uppercase and abbreviations and such. Example: Locale.US or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2005-nov-12", formatter);
```

The syntax is nearly the same though.

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2005-nov-12' could not be parsed at index 5

Comment: This happens because your default Locale expects the 'N' of 'Nov' to be upper case.

Comment: See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38904830/642706) to a similar Question for more discussion of this approach.

Answer (score 14):

You may have to go from DateTime to LocalDate.

Using Joda Time:

```
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
DateTime dateTime = FORMATTER.parseDateTime("2005-nov-12");
LocalDate localDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Comment: Note that this answer refers to Joda, not Java SE.

Answer (score 9):

Datetime formatting is performed by the `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter class`. Three classes provide *factory methods to create formatters*, and this is one. The others are `ISODateTimeFormat` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
LocalDate lDate = new LocalDate().parse("2005-nov-12",format);
```

`final org.joda.time.LocalDate class` is an immutable datetime class representing a date *without a time zone*. `LocalDate` is *thread-safe and immutable*, provided that the *Chronology* is as well. All standard Chronology classes supplied are thread-safe and immutable.

Answer (score 6):

`DateTimeFormatter`  has in-built formats that can directly be used to parse a character sequence. It is case Sensitive, Nov will work however nov and
NOV wont work:

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");

try {
    LocalDate datetime = LocalDate.parse(oldDate, pattern);
    System.out.println(datetime); 
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    // DateTimeParseException - Text '2019-nov-12' could not be parsed at index 5
    // Exception handling message/mechanism/logging as per company standard
}
```

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` provides custom way to create a formatter. It is Case Insensitive, Nov , nov and NOV will be treated as same.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")).toFormatter();
try {
    LocalDate datetime = LocalDate.parse(oldDate, f);
    System.out.println(datetime); // 2019-11-12
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
     // Exception handling message/mechanism/logging as per company standard
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your answer and provide a bit more explanations, how it relates to the question, where you got your solution from, why it works? For more guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer