# date is malformed when sending as json

Tags: java, json, backbone-model

I am trying to send json to server and i get the following exception:

> Resolving exception from handler [public void
>   com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI.createInvestAdjust(com.hexgen.ro.request.InvestAdjustRO,boolean)]:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Invalid format: "01/09/2012" is malformed at
>   "/09/2012" (through reference chain:
>   com.hexgen.ro.request.InvestAdjustRO["transDate"]); nested exception
>   is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Invalid format:
>   "01/09/2012" is malformed at "/09/2012" (through reference chain:
>   com.hexgen.ro.request.InvestAdjustRO["transDate"])

and this is what is my JSON:

```
adjustmentType: "UAMORT"
custodian: "DEUTSCHE"
debitCredit: "CREDIT"
investCategory: "FVTPL"
isUploaded: false
portfolio: "HEXGENFUND"
portfolioCcy: "INR"
recRemarks: "Test"
transDate: "01/09/2012"
transRef: "OP120010020000017"
```

this is what is my java code with getter and setter :

```
private String transId;
    private String portfolio;
    private String portfolioCcy;
    private String transRef;
    private String adjustmentType;
    private LocalDate transDate;
    private String debitCredit;
    private String investCategory;
    private String custodian;
    private String recRemarks;
    private RecStatus recStatus;
    private Boolean isUploaded=true;
```

what is the issure here and why do i get

> nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   Invalid format: "01/09/2012" is malformed at "/09/2012" (through
>   reference chain: com.hexgen.ro.request.InvestAdjustRO["transDate"])

thanks

Comment: JSON does not have a date data type and your error message seems to complaint about the date format. What exact date format does the server expect?

Comment: i have not given any format

Comment: Do you mean that you are using an undocumented web service?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746084/string-to-localdate

Comment: I think this is a Jackson issue, not a JSON issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this annotation to specify your date format:

```
private String transId;
private String portfolio;
private String portfolioCcy;
private String transRef;
private String adjustmentType;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate transDate;
private String debitCredit;
private String investCategory;
private String custodian;
private String recRemarks;
private RecStatus recStatus;
private Boolean isUploaded=true;
```