# How to convert a String of format yyyymmdd to LocalDate in JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a String in the form "20140518". How to convert it into LocalDate object

I tried this

```
this.todayDate = new LocalDate(val);
System.out.println(todayDate.toString("yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

When I try dumping this to standard output it dumps like 20140518-junk-junk. That it dumps a garbage string . I thought it would dump like 2014-05-18.

Comment: Its parsing the `210140518` as a year.  You have to give it a hint as to what the digits mean.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MM` that represents Month instead of `mm` that represents minutes.

Use `LocalDate.parse()` instead of `new LocalDate()` to construct the `LocalDate` object.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate lDate = org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse("20140518", format);
System.out.println(lDate);
```

output:

```
2014-05-18
```

---

[org.joda.time.LocalDate#toString()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toString%28%29) be default uses `yyyy-MM-dd` pattern.

You don't need to use `todayDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: LocalDate.parse is not a method in LocalDate. I can do LocalDateTime.parse I think but not LocalDate.parse. I want to return LocalDate not LocalDateTime

Comment: Find it here [LocalDate.parse()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29). check the imports please

Comment: Hey thanks Braj. I have imported mport org.joda.time.LocalDate. I am usning Java 1.7. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Is the issue resolved if yes then close the thread.

Comment: So, maybe I need to do it the hard way. Use DateTime as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746084/string-to-localdate

Comment: I have `joda-time-2.1.jar` in my project.