# Create LocalDate Object from Integers

Tags: java, date, java-8, jsr310

If I already have a date's month, day, and year as integers, what's the best way to use them to create a `LocalDate` object? I found this post [String to LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746084/string-to-localdate) , but it starts with a `String` representation of the date.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`LocalDate#of(int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) method that takes year, month and dayOfMonth.

Comment: Months and days start at `1` (this may seem obvious, but this is Java).

Answer (score 20):

You can create LocalDate like this, using ints

```
      LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.of(year,month,dayOfMonth);
```

and to create LocalDate from String you can use

```
      String date = "04/04/2004";
      inputDate = LocalDate.parse(date,
                      DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

You can use other formats too but you have to change String in forPattern(...)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Rohit's answer you can use this code to get Localdate from String

```
    String str = "2015-03-15";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Comment: The format shown here ( year-month-date ) complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use that standard by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern; you can skip the `DateTimeFormatter`. Let `LocalDate` directly parse that string, like this: `… = LocalDate.parse( "2015-03-15" );`