# Comparing dates as strings in Java

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I am having troubles comparing dates as strings. I am required to iterate through a collection and compare the date value of each object against 2 dates passed as parameters. The dates are all stored as strings and am required to keep them that way.

It is known that the dates will all be formatted `YYYY-MM-DD`. Below is a quick example of what I mean. Thanks all!

```
public ArrayList<Object> compareDates(String dateOne, String dateTwo) {
    for(Object object : objectCollection) {
        String objectDate = object.getDate();
        if(objectDate.equals(dateOne) || objectDate.equals(dateTwo)) { // Unsure of how to determine if the objects date is inbetween the two given dates
            //add object to collection
        }
    }
return  collection;
}
```

Comment: why would you want to compare dates as Strings? there are tons of tools to make comparisons of dates easy and precise, why not use those?

Comment: convert to a date object before compare is the only sane method

Comment: If you really want to stick to `String`s, then split them by `"-"` and compare the separated values. You may have to cast them to `int` then...

Comment: Maybe you can use the `SimpleDateFormat` to make concrete `Date` objects out of your string and compare these.

Comment: The example above doesn't look complete, i.e. it doesn't contain the defintion of the `objectCollection` variable. Like @Stultuske said, why compare them as streings? You can parse them in to `Calendar`s or `Date`s which are comparable.

Comment: `Object` does not contain a `getDate` method. Thus, this code is not supposed to compile.

Comment: Yes. I understand the code is incomplete and wont compile. That is not exactly what my code looks like but is just a random example to get my point across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your dates are in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, a lexicographic comparison can be used to determine the ordering between two dates. Thus, you can just use the [`String.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) method to compare the strings:

```
int c1 = objectDate.compareTo(dateOne);
int c2 = objectDate.compareTo(dateTwo);
if ((c1 >= 0 && c2 <= 0) || (c1 <= 0 && c2 >= 0)) {
    // objectDate between dateOne and dateTwo (inclusive)
}
```

If it is guaranteed that `dateOne < dateTwo`, then you can just use `(c1 >= 0 && c2 <= 0)`. To exclude the date bounds, use strict inequalities (`>` and `<`).

Comment: Agreed with your answer. However, I *guess* what the author of the question has trouble doing is not so much comparing the strings, but rather, how to express/implement a "between" relationship in terms of String.compareTo(), which returns an int. Maybe you could expand your answer to address this part too. (@ernest_k's answer was just posted, adding such an explanation)

Comment: Thank you for this! Between yours and @ernest_k's answer it makes a lot of sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure you need to follow:

1. Convert both String dateOne, String dateTwo into
   `java.time.LocalDate`
2. Iterate over your ArrayList and convert the indexed string into `java.time.LocalDate`

   **Note:** You need to accept `ArrayList<String>` in order to parse the string to LocalDate, not `ArrayList<Object>`
3. Do the comparison

[Refer to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to implement the comparison logic.

You may refer to [this link for additional help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538939/4506140).

Answer (score 0):

As your dates are in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, then String's `compareTo` should return consistent results:

```
if(objectDate.compareTo(dateOne) >= 0 && objectDate.compareTo(dateTwo) <= 0)
```

This roughly checks (conceptually): `objectDate >= dateOne && objectdate <= dateTwo`

That's just if one must use string's methods. A better approache, though, would be to convert the strings to date objects and perform a date-based comparisons.

Comment: I don't think conversion to date is better. String comparison is fast, conversion is slow, and if the OP is supposed to keep the dates as they are, it means converting every time.

Comment: Maybe you could stress that your implementation works only when `dateOne` is before `dateTwo`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Not really. This is easy because it's just local date values. What if time zones, offsets, daylight savings complexities are introduced? Date/time types would clearly be more appropriate.

Comment: Comparing strings is just going through them once. Converting them requires going through them once, and then also doing validity checks for the day and month.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Not arguing your point. You're talking performance, I'm talking accuracy. But you've got a valid point, not disputing that.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I know it seems kind of odd to keep them as Strings but my prof wont allow me to convert them to a date object even though it seemed vastly simpler to me.

Answer (score 0):

If dateOne is before dateTwo you can use following comparison if you like have date inbetween.

```
    public ArrayList<Object> compareDates(List<Object> objectCollection, String start, String end) {
        ArrayList<Object> dateBetween = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object object : objectCollection) {
            LocalDate objectDate = parseDate(object.getDate());
            if( !objectDate.isBefore(parseDate(start)) && !objectDate.isAfter(parseDate(end))) {
                dateBetween.add(object);
            }
        }
        return dateBetween;
    }

    private LocalDate parseDate(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD");
        return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    }
```

Comment: Parsing `start` and `end` at each loop iteration may be quiete expensive...

Comment: Yes, but comparing date as strings seems for me a bit tricky.

Comment: You could parse them, as dates, once at the start of the method. Just a thought.

Comment: Does this increase performance, after all you have the same number of dates to parse?

Comment: If you have N items in the collection, with the current code, you call `parseDate` 3 times (1 for `object.getDate`, one for `start`, once for `end`) on each iterations, so `3*N` times total. But only `N+2` times are necessary (once and only once for `start` and `end`, and once for each of the N objects). That is a lot of unnecessary `DateTimeFormatter` instanciation and calls to `parse` if you happen to have a huge list.