# How to create LocalDate objects from a String like "[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]"

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, localdate, localdatetime

in the RESTController of a Spring Boot Application I retrieve a requestBody as JSON which looks like this:

```
{id=-1, name=test, street=test, houseNumber=1, postalCode=66111, city=Saarbrücken, sleepingSpots=2, unavailableDates=[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]}
```

I want to create a couch object with the values from this json string, so I try to call constructor and pass the values like this:

```
new Couch(requestBody.get("name"),..., Integer.parseInt(requestBody.get("postalCode")), ...)
```

So far, it works fine.

Trouble begins with unavailableDates. Class Couch has attribute:

```
List<LocalDate> unavailabeDates;
```

So I try to create a LocalDate object for each date which is inside unavailabeDate part of the json request.

Can you help me to do so?

Comment: Is this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746203/11121568

Comment: No, this is just how to convert one string with one date into LocalDate. But I have a list with various count of dates and timestamps as string. I can't manage to split every date and time.

Comment: Cant, you loop through your list of strings and deserialize them one by one into your list of `LocalDate`s? If you provide the code of your `Couch`  class, I can write you the deserializer.

Comment: I'm not having a list yet:
I have a string like this:
"[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]"
and looking for a way to convert it into a List<String> like this:
["2022-06-29", "2022-06-30"]

Comment: Ok I will code it in answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you showed **is not JSON**. JSON would look like:

```
{
"id"=-1, "name"="test"
}
```

For example - quotes around strings. I'm guessing you are getting real JSON, throwing it through a crappy JSON parsing library you should not be using (such as `org.json`) that turned it into a `Map<String, Object>`, and you then called `.toString()` on that.

So, immediate step 1: Search the web for a tutorial on Jackson or GSON, these are JSON parsing libraries you want to use. These 'unmarshall' JSON into a class you make, so, you make a java class that looks like this data, i.e.:

```
class WhateverThisIs {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<LocalDate> unavailableDates;
}
```

and in many ways your problem is already solved.

There is a slight weirdness going on here - whatever is making this data is confused about date handling. That's more or less normal, virtually all programming languages are rather fundamentally broken. Java, fortunately, isn't, since Java8 and the introduction of the `java.time` package (`java.util.Date`, and `java.util.Calendar` are worthless, don't use those).

At any rate, having `00:00:00` in a date string that is not supposed to represent time in the first place is problematic, a JSON unmarshaller will probably not silently just assume that those zeroes can be ignored. You can trivially make your own code that turns those strings into a LocalDate, and you can strip the dates off.

If you really, really do not want to use unmarshalling JSON libraries for some crazy reason, note that your input is most likely a `List<String>` then, with the list always having 2 dates (the start and the end one). You can turn a string into a LocalDate (the right datatype for what this data is representing) as follows:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter MY_DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

public LocalDate String parse(String in) {
  var ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(in, MY_DATE_FORMAT);
  return ldt.toLocalDate();
}

// example:


parse("2022-06-29 00:00:00.000");
```

You can use the same code if you're writing custom unmarshalling code to turn that string into the requisite `LocalDate`.

Comment: Thank for your effort. But this is not what I want to do and not my problem. You Try to explain me how to create LocalDate with a custom formatter...

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain more exactly:

This is the method in my controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(value = "/couch", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public CouchDto postCouch(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestBody) {
    LOGGER.info("POST /couch was called with request body: " + requestBody);
    return newCouch = SERVICE.createCouch(
            requestBody.get("name"), 
            requestBody.get("street"), 
            requestBody.get("houseNumber"), 
            Integer.parseInt(requestBody.get("postalCode")), 
            requestBody.get("city"), 
            Integer.parseInt(requestBody.get("sleepingSpots")),
            requestBody.get("unavailableDates"), // here I want to pass List<LocalDate>, maybe List<LocalDateTime>
            Integer.parseInt(requestBody.get("owner")));
}
```

requestBody contains the following "JSON" (I know this is just a String that looks simular to JSON, but this is what I get from HTTP Request from a Flutter app...):

```
{id=-1, name=Testcouch, street=Test, houseNumber=1, postalCode=123456, city=test, sleepingSpots=2, unavailableDates=[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000], owner=1}
```

I'm able to pass all values to the constructor by calling requestBody.get("value"). Sometime I have to parse it to an integer, like postalCode or owner.

But when I try to create date objects, it is not possible because:

```
requestBody.get("unavailableDates")
```

delivers a string like this:

```
"[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]"
```

What I need to create a LocalDateTime object is a List like:

```
["2022-06-29 00:00:00.000", "2022-06-30 00:00:00.000"]
```

With that I can easily loop over all list entries and create the objects... But I don't know how to get there...

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if it is what you want or not? I'll help you till you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments:

> I'm not having a list yet: I have a string like this: "[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]" and looking for a way to convert it into a List like this: ["2022-06-29", "2022-06-30"] –

By the given example

First thing to do is to remove brackets: `[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]` -> `2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000`

Then split it by `,` to get an array of: `2022-06-29 00:00:00.000`,  `2022-06-30 00:00:00.000` and stream over it.

Trim redundant white spaces:  `2022-06-30 00:00:00.000` -> `2022-06-30 00:00:00.000`

Split each datetime by `white space` to separate date from time and get index 0 of it because date is first thing before `whitespace`

At the collect it as an array of dates that we wanted in first place.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timestamps = "[2022-06-29 00:00:00.000, 2022-06-30 00:00:00.000]";
        timestamps = removeBrackets(timestamps);
        List<String> timestampsInList = Arrays.stream(timestamps.split(","))//
                .map(String::trim)// Remove first and last white spaces.
                .map(datetime -> datetime.split(" ")[0])// Split datetime by white space to separate date from time 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(timestampsInList);
    }

    public static String removeBrackets(String str) {
        // Removing first and last character
        // of a string using substring() method
        return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
[2022-06-29, 2022-06-30]
```

Comment: Thank you this is almost the right solution. But I still get an error:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-06-28 00:00:00.000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
Seems that there are problems with the MY_DATE_FORMAT and the "."

Comment: The `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` is not from my code for sure. Can I see your source code? I'm sure that i can help you.

Comment: I wrote a new answer to offer a better overview of the code for you.

Comment: Excellent job, Steven! I will clean your code and post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This is the service class where a couch object should be created:

```
...

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS");

...

    //""""""""""""""""""""""" Couch functionality """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""//
        public CouchDto createCouch(String name, String street, String houseNumber, int postalCode, String city,
                int sleepingSpots, String unavailableDates, int owner) {
            
    
            return new CouchDto(name, street, houseNumber, postalCode, city, sleepingSpots, this.getDateList(unavailableDates), owner);
        }
    
        private List<LocalDateTime> getDateList(String unavailableDates) {
            unavailableDates = this.removeBrackets(unavailableDates);
            List<String> unavailableDatesInStringList = Arrays.stream(unavailableDates.split(",")).map(String::trim)
                    .map(datetime -> datetime.split(" ")[0])// Split datetime by white space to separate date from time
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println(unavailableDatesInStringList);
            List<LocalDateTime> unavailabeDateList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String date : unavailableDatesInStringList) {
                unavailabeDateList.add(LocalDateTime.parse(date, DATE_FORMAT));
            }
            return unavailabeDateList;
        }
    
        private String removeBrackets(String str) {
            return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
        }
```

When createCouch gets triggered the following error occurs:

```
2022-06-25 20:34:21.219 ERROR 7984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-06-28 00:00:00.000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19] with root cause

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-06-28 00:00:00.000' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
```

Answer (score 0):

This Answer is Just a clean version of [Steven's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72756756/11121568) which the idea of it was taken from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72756056/11121568).

```java
//""""""""""""""""""""""" Couch functionality """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""//
    public CouchDto createCouch(String name, String street, String houseNumber, int postalCode, String city,
            int sleepingSpots, String unavailableDates, int owner) {
        

        return new CouchDto(name, street, houseNumber, postalCode, city, sleepingSpots, this.getDateList(unavailableDates), owner);
    }

    private List<LocalDateTime> getDateList(String unavailableDates) {
        unavailableDates = this.removeBrackets(unavailableDates);
        return Arrays.stream(unavailableDates.split(","))//
                .map(String::trim)// Remove first and last white spaces.
                .map(datetime -> datetime.split(" ")[0])// Split datetime by white space to separate date from time
                .map(datetime -> LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, DATE_FORMAT))// Convert string to LocalDateTime by DATE_FORMAT
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private String removeBrackets(String str) {
        return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    }
```