# Format date from String to LocalDate

Tags: java, date, parsing, localdate

I have a problem parsing a `String` to `LocalDate`.
According to similar questions on Stackoverflow and documentation I am using the correct values ​​dd (day of the month), MM (month of the year) and yyyy (year).

My String

```java
String mydate = "18.10.2022 07:50:18";
```

My parsing test code

```java
System.out.println(
    LocalDate.parse(testPasswordExp)
             .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    )
);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text '18.10.2022 07:50:18' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: This looks like you need a `LocalDateTime` instead of a `LocalDate`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String to LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746084/string-to-localdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the specified format for parsing, you use it to format the parsed date.

```java
LocalDate.parse(mydate)
```

… uses the default [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) format. You are looking for this overload:

```java
LocalDate.parse(mydate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

This method uses the specified format for parsing string to date. See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/evbnNp).

Note that you are using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), meaning it will throw away the time part, keeping only the date after parsing. You probably meant to use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Comment: @deHaar No it won't, i tested it before posting the answer.

Comment: @deHaar the code in this answer works for me (JDK 17 on Windows 10), i.e. no `DateTimeParseException`

Comment: OK, I tested it with a later version and that indeed worked.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem of your code example is that you first parse the `String` to a `LocalDate` without the use of a suitable `DateTimeFormatter` and then `format()` it with a `DateTimeFormatter` that tries to format hour of day, minute of hour and second of minute which just aren't there in a `LocalDate`.

You can parse this `String` to a `LocalDate` directly, but better parse it to a `LocalDateTime` because your `String` contains more than just information about

- day of month
- month of year
- year

Your `myDate` (and probably the `testPasswordExp`, too) has a time of day. You can get a `LocalDate` as the final result that way, too, because a `LocalDateTime` can be narrowed down `toLocalDate()`.

A possible way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example datetime
    String testPasswordExp = "18.10.2022 07:50:18";
    
    System.out.println(
        LocalDateTime   // use a LocalDateTime and…
            .parse(     // … parse …
                testPasswordExp,    // … the datetime using a specific formatter,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss")
            ).toLocalDate() // then extract the LocalDate
    );
}
```

Output:

```
2022-10-18
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm parsing it because i have to comapre two dates, but now i know i have to separately comapre date and time.

Comment: If you want, you may parse it into a `LocalDate`, but it’s not advisable. Better to go through a `LocalDateTime` as shown in the answer. And if right for your situation, you can compare two `LocalDateTime` objects using their `isBefore` or `isAfter` method -- provided that both are in the same time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    String mydate = "18.10.2022 07:50:18";


    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(mydate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

    System.out.println(ld.toString());
```

Comment: This Answer repeats the content of the earlier [Answer by Chaosfire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73618585/642706).